# Flutter - How to make SnackBar to not push FloatingActionButton upward?

Tags: android, flutter, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

How to make the `Snackbar` to overlap the `FloatingActionButton` and not push it up upward when popped up? I've attached my simplified code for reference. Thank you in advance.

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ScreenState();
}

class ScreenState extends State<Screen>{

  BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: action,
    ),
    body: Builder(
      builder : (BuildContext context){
        this.context = context;
        return Container();
      }
    )
  );

  action() => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds : 1000),
    content: Container(height: 10)
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use multiple `Scaffold`s. Wrap the inner one with an outer one. Use inner to put everything belong to it, `body`, `appBar`, `bottomNavigationBar`, `floatingActionButton` and so on. Call `showSnackBar` from outer's `body`'s `BuildContext`. If any, move `drawer` from inner to outer to keep it above the `SnackBar`.

If you prefer to popup the `SnackBar` like a classic toast, see Siddharth Patankar's answer. Thank you for that too.

Below is the simplified code for my answer.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    drawer : Drawer(child: Container()),
    body: Builder(
      builder : (BuildContext context){
        this.context = context;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds : 1000),
              content: Container(height: 30),
            )),
          ),
        );
      }
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 15):

You can set the `behavior` property of the `SnackBar` to `SnackBarBehavior.floating` which will display the `Snackbar` above other widgets.

This should do it -

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ScreenState();
}

class ScreenState extends State<Screen>{

  BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: action,
    ),
    body: Builder(
      builder : (BuildContext context){
        this.context = context;
        return Container();
      }
    )
  );

  action() => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds : 1000),
    content: Container(height: 10)
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating, // Add this line
  ));
}
```

See [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBarBehavior-class.html) link for more information.

Comment: thank you. good solution. is there any way to make it overlaid?

Comment: Could you please elaborate by what you mean by overlaid? Because the solution I provided already displays the `SnackBar` above other widgets.

Comment: overlapping like in a `Stack`

Comment: As far as I know, it won't be possible directly with the `SnackBar` widget. You might need to create your own custom widget for that and then wrap it in a `Stack`.
Also, an overlapping `SnackBar` is not recommended as per the official [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/components/snackbars/#placement) from Google.

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your problem,  please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: your comment is enough to answer the question. don't need to show code. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

## SnackBar Overlap FAB (Basic)

[image]

To have a SnackBar overlap a FAB, the FAB should be placed on a nested Scaffold.

```
class BasicOverlapFAB extends StatelessWidget {
  const BasicOverlapFAB();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Basic Overlap'),
      ),
      body: Scaffold( // ← Nested
        body: Center(child: Text('SnackBar will overlap FAB'),),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_double_arrow_down),
          onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('This overlaps the FAB'),)
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This works because a SnackBar is shown on the highest Scaffold nearest to a ScaffoldMessenger.  The nearest ScaffoldMessenger is included in `MaterialApp` by default.

In the above code, the Scaffold showing the SnackBar is parent/above the Scaffold with a FAB, thus Snack overlaps FAB.

```
MaterialApp
  ScaffoldMessenger
    Scaffold ← Snacks here
      Scaffold
        FAB
```

## Nested `Scaffolds` & `ScaffoldMessengers`

[image: SnackBar overlap FAB]

This example has several nested Scaffolds.

Scaffolds are like panes (layers) of glass.  We can stack one on top of another.  And we can show FABs, SnackBars and other widgets on each layer.

To make the layers of Scaffolds easier to see, each Scaffold is smaller and is outlined with a different color: blue, green, red.  Red is the furthest down.  (Nested panes go underneath.)

`Scaffolds` don't provide a `ScaffoldMessenger` by default, but `MaterialApp` provides a default `ScaffoldMessenger`.  Most of the time we're interacting with this default "root" `ScaffoldMessenger`, but we can add our own.

For each layer of Scaffold in this example (`AnotherScaffold` custom class) we **manually added its own `ScaffoldMessenger`**.  Each also has a FAB that shows SnackBars on its own `ScaffoldMessenger`.

Copy/Paste & play around with this in an emulator to get a feel for how the Scaffolds/ScaffoldMessengers form layers & how they overlap & interact.

```
class NestedScaffoldsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedScaffoldsPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container( // unnecessary container just for border color / educational visibility
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
      ),
      child: Scaffold(// Root Scaffold for FAB #0
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Nested Scaffolds'),
        ),
        body: AnotherScaffold(// Nested Scaffold & FAB #1
          level: 1,
          color: Colors.green,
          body: AnotherScaffold(// Nested Scaffold & FAB #2
            level: 2,
            color: Colors.red,
            body: Center(child: Text('3 Total Scaffolds')),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( // FAB #0
          child: Text('0'),
          onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text('Snack level 0'),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating, // SnackBar will show above FAB
                //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.fixed, // default, pushes FAB up
              )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnotherScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final int level;
  final Widget body;
  final Color color;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> smState;

  AnotherScaffold({
    required this.level,
    required this.color,
    required this.body,
  }) : smState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  /// This GlobalKey, given to a ScaffoldMessenger, will uniquely identify that
  /// ScaffoldMessenger.  We can then use it to show SnackBars.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: smState, // use this key to show SnackBars on this ScaffoldMessenger
      child: Container( // unnecessary container just for border color / educational visibility
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: color),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: body,
          floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: (level) * 40),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: GlobalKey(), // unique tag req'd for multiple FABs
              backgroundColor: color,
              child: Text('$level'),
              onPressed: () => // using smState key to show a SnackBar on that ScaffoldMessenger
                  smState.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
                    content: Text('Snack level $level'),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```